# Prove or disprove the quasi-concavity and quasi-convexity of $f(x,y)=xa^{y-1}+b$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, optimization, convex-analysis

Consider $f(x,y)=xa^{y-1}+b$ for $(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2_{++}$, $a\in(0,1)$, and $b\in\mathbb{R}$. I am trying to evaluate the quasi-concavity/quasi-convexity of $f$.

**My attempt:** To see quasi-concavity, consider $g(x,y)=ln(x)+(y-1)ln(a)$. The Bordered Hessian for $g$ is

\begin{pmatrix}
0&\frac{1}{x}&ln(a)\\
\frac{1}{x}&-\frac{1}{x^2}& 0\\
ln(a)& 0&0
\end{pmatrix}

The determinant of the 1st order Bordered Hessian is $-\frac{1}{x^2}<0$, and the determinant of the Bordered Hessian itself is $(\frac{ln(a)}{x})^2>0$. This alternation of signs implies that $g$ is quasi-concave. Consider $h(x)=e^x+b$, which clearly is increasing. We have that $f(x,y)=h(g(x,y))$, so as $g$ is quasi-concave and $h$ an increasing transformation, $f$ is quasi-concave as well.

**Where I'm stuck at** is figuring out if $f(x,y)$ is quasi-convex also. I've tried different transformations to use a similar technique to the one I used showing quasi-concavity, but without much luck. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: @LinAlgThe matrix for the analysis is correct (the logaritmhmic transform of $f$). $g_x=1/x$, $g_y=ln(a)$, and that's row 1 and column 1. Then, the rest of the matrix is just the hessian of $g$, where the only second-order derivative that survives is $-1/x^2$. What is wrong, as you point out, is the name, it is not the bordered hessian (very similar though, if we think of an unconstrained maximization problem). The test I rely on is Theorem 8.9 in "A first course in optimization theory" by Sundaram.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function is not quasiconvex. For quasiconvexity, the sublevel set $\left\{ (x,y) : f(x,y) \leq \alpha\right\}$ needs to be convex for any $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$. Take $\alpha = 1+b$, then you need $\{(x,y) : x \leq c^{y-1}\}$ to be convex (with $c = 1/a > 1$). This set is clearly not convex, because $(x,y)=(1,1)$ and $(x,y)=(c^{2},3)$ are in the sublevel set, but the midpoint $(x,y)=((1+c^2)/2, 2)$ is not.